# How to set X and Z axis to 0 after transform.rotation in c#

Tags: c#, 3d

Recently I start using C# instead of JAVA and I don't know how to set a value in a eulerangle only for one axis.

Maybe I don't need to do that, so better I explain what I'm doing:

I have a 3D object (player) that look at mouse pointer, but when the mouse pointer it's too close to the object, it's change his x and z axis, and I need to set it to 0 to keep standing the object.

In java I just write this after transform.rotation:

```
transform.eulerAngles.x = 0;
transform.eulerAngles.z = 0;
```

In C# I can't do that. Is there a simple way to do it? My code is:

```
Ray ray = Camera.main.GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
RaycastHit hit_A;
if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit_A, Mathf.Infinity, GroundMask)){
    Vector3 rotPoint = new Vector3 (hit_A.point.x - transform.position.x, transform.position.y, hit_A.point.z - transform.position.z);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(rotPoint);
}
```

Maybe, as I said, there are an other way to fix this. I'm open to any solution. I searh it on google, but because at my english level I don't understand the results

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`transform.eulerAngles` and `transform.rotation` are properties with pass-by-value semantics, not pass-by-reference. That means whenever you use them, a copy of that object is created and passed to the caller. When you make changes to that copy, they won't be applied to the object it came from until you explicitly write it back.

You can tell that because according to the documentation both [`Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) and [`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) are `struct`s, not `class`es. One subtle difference between Java and C# which can trip up someone who switches from one to the other is that in C#, classes are passed by reference just like in Java but C# struct's are passed by value.

Another thing you need to get used to as a Java programmer learning C# is that the syntax `object.identifier` can mean more than just directly accessing a public variable. That "public variable" can in fact be implemented as a [Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), which means that getting and setting it invokes some hidden program logic.

So what happens in the line `transform.eulerAngles.x = 0;` is as follows:

1. The Quaternion which represents the rotation of the transform get converted to a `new Vector3` (Unity internally handles all rotations as quaternions. The Vector3 representation are just for your convenience)
2. That Vector3 is passed to the caller
3. The caller changes the x-member of the Vector3
4. The Vector3 gets discarded

So if you want to change the rotations, you need to copy them to a local variable, change that local variable, and then write that variable back:

```
Vector3 rotationAngles = Transform.eulerAngles;
rotationAngles.x = 0.0f;
rotationAngles.z = 0.0f;
transform.eulerAngles = rotationAngles;
```

By the way, if the Unity API would be in Java, the code might look something like this:

```
Vector3 rotationAngles = transform.createRotationEulerAngles();
rotationAngles.x = 0.0f;
rotationAngles.z = 0.0f;
transform.setRotation(rotationAngles);
```

Comment: I make a comment to your answer, but the format its ugly. My answer is in response at yours, thank you!!!

Comment: @letramuda The reason it didn't work might be that I set x and y to 0, not x and z like in your question. Another reason might be that you inserted it at the wrong place in your code. You would need to add it below `transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(rotPoint);`.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, thanks Philipp for your explanation. I did what you said but it didn't work. I don't know why, but using your answer I found a way to do it. It's the same, but write like this it works, and, like I said, I don't know why (i'm so newbie scripting).

```
Vector3 rotationAngles = new Vector3 (0, transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);
transform.eulerAngles = rotationAngles;
```

Now the player looks to the pointer. Thank you so much!!